# Change the color of background image using css

Tags: html, css

I have a library of icons I want to use in my application. These are mostly glyphicons but with a few others thrown in. I'm wanting the html to look the same as would be defined for a glyphicon, namely

```
<a href="#">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span>
    Normal Link
</a>

<a href="#">
    <span class="glyphicon blue .glyphicon-wrench"></span>
    Blue Link
</a>
```

I realize that glphicons are actually a *font*, not images typically, but due to requirements that are beyond my control I can't rely on the font being installed/available; so I have to use background images instead.

CSS:

```
.glyphicon {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    margin-right: 5px;
    content: "";
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    color: transparent;
}

.glyphicon .glyphicon-wrench: {
    background-image: url('../images/glyphicons_free/glyphicons/png/glyphicons-440-wrench.png');
}

.glyphicon .glyphicon-envelope {
    background-image: url('../images/glyphicons_free/glyphicons/png/glyphicons-11-envelope.png');
}

.glyphicon .glyphicon-info-sign {
    background-image: url('../images/glyphicons_free/glyphicons/png/glyphicons-196-info-sign.png');
}

.glyphicon .glyphicon-danger {
    background-image: url('../images/glyphicons_free/glyphicons/png/glyphicons-197-exclamation-sign.png');
}
```

This issue is that I need the icon to be different colors in different places. So I want the ".blue" class and ".white" class to change the image color accordingly. Right now I'm doing this by creating a using a image editor to create a different color image and having a section for each color:

```
.glyphicon .blue .glyphicon-wrench: {
    background-image: url('../images/glyphicons_free/glyphicons/png/glyphicons-440-wrench-blue.png');
}

.glyphicon .blue .glyphicon-envelope {
    background-image: url('../images/glyphicons_free/glyphicons/png/glyphicons-11-envelope-blue.png');
}

.glyphicon .blue .glyphicon-info-sign {
    background-image: url('../images/glyphicons_free/glyphicons/png/glyphicons-196-info-sign-blue.png');
}

.glyphicon .blue .glyphicon-danger {
    background-image: url('../images/glyphicons_free/glyphicons/png/glyphicons-197-exclamation-sign-blue.png');
}
```

I really don't like having to create all these extra images though and repeat myself for each color. Is there a way that I can apply a *filter* to the *Background-Image* of a html element, something like...

```
.glyphicon .blue {
     background-filter: RGB(0,0,1);
}
```

**note**

I know it is possible to apply a filter to an IMG tag, I need to be able to apply one to a *background-image*.  These icons also have transparent backgrounds which need to remain transparent.... So I need a filter that only affects the image's foreground.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: use an svg then you can change the fill colour, by the way, your selectors look wrong - you shouldn't have a space between your classes.  Also why can't you use @font-face to import the glyphicons - that way they will always be available

Comment: There are lots os options here. You could have all images in one color and use `filter: hue-rotate` to change their colors, there are many ways to change the color with filters. Or you could have an SVG as @Pete mentioned, you could also put a range of your font in your CSS with base64 and font-face then just use `color` as default.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use fonts, try inlining an SVG sprite at the top of your html.

Hide the SVG sprite itself, but you can reference each *icon* of the sprite via its unique id later in your html with the [`<use>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use).

Set `fill` color within the SVG with `fill="currentColor"`, you can add `color` with CSS to a any parent node to control the color of each icon instance.

```css
#svgSprite {
  display: none
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}

.green {
  color: green;
}

.yellow {
  color: yellow;
}

.blue:hover {
  color: navy;
}

.red:hover {
  color: maroon
}

.green:hover {
  color: DarkGreen;
}

.yellow:hover {
  color: DarkOliveGreen;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svgSprite" viewBox="0 0 122 122">
<g id="checkbox">
<rect x="3.5" y="3.5" width="115" height="115"  stroke="black" stroke-width="5" fill="none"/>
<path d="M57 110L15 62L57 85L107 14L57 110Z" fill="currentColor"/>
</g>
</svg>


<div class="icon blue"><svg><use href="#checkbox"/></svg></div>
<div class="icon red"><svg><use href="#checkbox"/></svg></div>
<div class="icon green"><svg><use href="#checkbox"/></svg></div>
<div class="icon yellow"><svg><use href="#checkbox"/></svg></div>
```